# How to deduce the energy of a pair of vortices the classical XY model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, integration

Consider a pair of oppositely charged vortices with unit strength, we estimate the energy of a pair of vortices as:
$$
E_{\text {pair }}-E_{0} \cong \frac{J}{2} \int d^{2} r(\nabla \theta)^{2}=\frac{J}{2} \int d^{2} r\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_{1}}{\left|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_{1}\right|^{2}}-\frac{\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2}}{\left|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2}\right|^{2}}\right)^{2}\\=\frac{J}{2} \int \frac{d^{2} k}{(2 \pi)^{2}} \frac{\left|e^{i k \cdot r_{1}}-e^{i k \cdot r_{2}}\right|^{2}}{k^{2}}=2 \pi J \ln \left(\frac{\left|\boldsymbol{r}_{1}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2}\right|}{a}\right)
$$
where $L$ is the size of the system, and $a$ is a short distance cutoff that can be thought of as the size of the vortex core, typically the lattice length, and $R$ is the radius between the vortex and the anti-vortex.

I do not quite understand how to transform from the $\boldsymbol{r}$ space to the $\boldsymbol{k}$ space, and whether the equality is a result of Parseval's theorem.

Comment: Are you just asking how to do the Fourier transfom in the second equation?

Comment: @mike stone Yes, this is one of the thing I need, and the second is the validity of the equation. Thnaks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that  Green function for
the Laplacian in the entire ${\mathbb R}^2$ is
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln|{\bf r}-{\bf r}'|/a
$$
and we also know that this should be  given by
$$
\int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{e^{i{\bf k}\cdot ({\bf r}-{\bf r}')}}{|{\bf k}|^2}
$$
The problem in relating the two expresions is   that this last integral diverges at small $k$ and there is no "$a$".

It is easiest to descend from higher dimenions. The  Green function for
the Laplacian in the entire ${\mathbb R}^n$ is
given by the sum over eigenfunctions
$$
g(r,r')= \int\frac{d^nk}{(2\pi)^n} \frac
{e^{i{\bf k}\cdot (r-r')}}{k^2}. 
$$
Thus
$$
-\nabla_r^2 g(r,r')= \int\frac{d^nk}{(2\pi)^n} 
{e^{i{\bf k}\cdot (r-r')}}=
\delta^n(r-r').
$$
We can evaluate the integral for any $n$ by using *Schwinger's trick* to turn the integrand  into a Gaussian:
$$
g(r,r')= \int_0^\infty ds \int\frac{d^nk}{(2\pi)^n}
e^{i{\bf k}\cdot (r-r')}e^{-sk^2} 
\nonumber\\
=
\int_0^\infty ds \left(\sqrt{\frac \pi s}\right)^n
\frac 1{(2\pi)^n} e^{-\frac{1}{4s}|r-r'|^2}
\nonumber\\
=
\frac 1{2^n\pi^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty dt\,
t^{\frac n2-2} e^{-t|r-r'|^2/4}
\nonumber\\
=
\frac 1{2^n\pi^{n/2}} \Gamma\left(\frac n2-1\right)
\left(\frac{|r-r'|^2}{4}\right)^{1-n/2}\nonumber\\
= \frac 1{(n-2)S_{n-1}}\left( \frac{1}{|r-r'|}\right)^{n-2}.
$$
Here, $\Gamma(x)$ is Euler's gamma function:
$$
\Gamma(x)= \int_0^\infty dt\, t^{x-1} e^{-t},
$$
and
$$
S_{n-1}= \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma (n/2)}
$$
is the surface area of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

For three dimensions we find the familiar
$$
 g(r,r')= \frac 1{4\pi} \frac 1{|r-r'|},\qquad n=3.
$$
In two dimensions the Fourier integral is divergent for
small $k$. We may control this divergence by using  pretending  that  $n$
is  a continuous variable and use
$$
\Gamma(x) = \frac 1 x \Gamma(x+1)
$$
together with
$$
a^x = e^{a\ln
x}= 1+a \ln x +\cdots
$$ to
to examine the behaviour of $g(r,r')$ near  $n= 2$:
$$
g(r,r')= \frac 1{4\pi}\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{(n/2-1)} \left(1-
(n/2-1)\ln( \pi |r-r'|^2)+O\left[(n-2)^2\right]\right)
\nonumber\\
= \frac 1{4\pi}\left( \frac {1}{n/2-1} - 2 \ln
|r-r'|- \ln \pi- \gamma +\cdots\right).
$$
Here $\gamma=-\Gamma'(1)=.57721\ldots$ is the
Euler-Mascheroni constant.
Although the
pole  $1/(n-2)$ blows up at $n=2$, it is  independent of position.
We simply  absorb it, and the  $-\ln {\pi}-\gamma$, into an undetermined
additive constant "$a$". Once we have done this, the  limit $n\to 2$ can
be taken and we find
$$
g(r,r') = -\frac 1{2\pi} \ln |r-r'|+\hbox{const.}, \qquad n=2.
$$
The constant does not affect the Green-function property, so we can chose any convenient value for it.